# Rollup with @types/d3 using Visual Studio Code

Tags: d3.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, rollup, umd

My library project uses...

- Typescript
- Rollup
- D3
- @types/d3

The package.json file has these dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/d3": "^4.4.0"  /* also tried moving this to devDeps */
},
"devDependencies": {
  "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
  "postcss-cssnext": "^2.9.0",
  "postcss-nested": "^1.0.0",
  "postcss-simple-vars": "^3.0.0",
  "rollup": "^0.40.1",
  "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^7.0.0",
  "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^0.4.0",
  "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^2.0.0",
  "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^0.2.0",
  "rollup-plugin-serve": "^0.1.0",
  "rollup-plugin-typescript": "^0.8.1",
  "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.1",
  "rollup-watch": "^3.1.0"
}
```

My rollup.config.js file has these plugins configured...

```
plugins: [
    typescript(),
    postcss({
        extension: ['.css'],
        plugins: [
            simplevars(),
            nested(),
            cssnext({ warnForDuplicates: false }),
            cssnano(),
        ],
    }),
    nodeResolve({
        jsnext: true,  //use jsnext if the node package supports it
        main: true,    //look for main file
        browser: true, //if there is a browser version, use it
    }),
    commonjs(),
    //uglify(),
    serve({
        contentBase: 'build',
        port: '80',
    }),
    livereload(),
]
```

Rollup builds it fine.  However, in the editor, VSCode displays an error on the d3 symbol.  When I hover over it I see this error...

> **[ts] 'd3' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.**

I can add this import to make the error go away in the editor.

```
import d3 from '@types/d3';
```

However, then rollup fails with...

> **Could not resolve '@types/d3' from '...'**

Is there a way to configure vscode to not show that error, so it doesn't drown out real errors?

Is there an alternative way to configure D3 type definitions in a rollup project?

Answer (score 2):

You only have the TypeScript typings for d3 defined. You still need to specify d3 as dependency.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/d3": "4.8.0",
  "d3": "4.8.0"
}
```

You can now import d3:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
```